# Laravel cashier with Stripe: invoice number

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, stripe-payments, laravel-5.4, laravel-cashier

Not sure it's the same elsewhere, but in my country, invoice numbers must be sequential for a service in a company.

My Laravel application sells a service via subscription. It must produce invoices with sequential numbers (`abcdef-0001`, `abcdef-0002`, etc.). I use Laravel Cashier with Stripe because both are easy to configure. Now I want to generate invoices. But Invoices in Laravel Cashier have no sequential numbers nowhere. I can access to one user "invoices" with:

```
$invoices = $user->invoices();
```

But it seems it's not really invoices, just **payment** informations from Stripe. Calling this function for each user to get the total number of invoices, then calculate the sequential number is not an option.

How can I handle a sequential number for invoices easily without breaking the simple model built by Laravel Cashier (+Stripe)? Is there a proper way to do this kind of thing? Or do I have to re-develop a whole system for such a need?

Answer (score 1):

Just create your own model BizInvoice, give it a field invoiceID (like you like it .. you can query the last invoice... get id ... increment by 1 with custom logic or just use the default id field) and make a relation with user model and Laravel cashier payments model.

This way you have an unique (real) invoices number(id) that you could access through user or/and payments

Comment: Thanks. The problem is I don't get "new" invoices. There is just a list of charges **by user**. So I have no clue in Laravel if something was charged recently. I can just know that by calling `$user->invoices()`on all users all the day (that's not an option, because it's a call to stripe API for each call)

Answer (score 0):

[Invoices in Laravel Cashier](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/billing#invoices) are actually an abstraction over the [Stripe invoice objects](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object). While Stripe provides a sequential invoice number, Cashier does not expose it for some reason, but there's an escape hatch: By calling [`asStripeInvoice()`](https://github.com/laravel/cashier-stripe/blob/86b53ce209f51359288177debd6222cef8f06126/src/Invoice.php#L482-L490) on the invoice object, you can retrieve the underlying Stripe object.

```php
$lastInvoice = $billable->invoices()->last();

// A sequential invoice number as provided by Stripe, 
// something like "6EEE0995-0001"
$invoiceNumber = $lastInvoice->asStripeInvoice()->number;
```